# Kong Gateway setup SSL certificate

Tags: kong

I got Kong Gateway running and would like to change/setup SSL certificate:

[image]

I managed to accomplish it via curl, following guide ( https://support.konghq.com/support/s/article/How-to-setup-Kong-to-serve-an-SSL-certificate-for-API-requests ).

However, is there a way to setup/change SSL certificate via helm configuration? Perhaps attach secret volume and pass certificate that way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around and asking Kong support for help, I got 2 ways to setup the cert.

If you want to experiment, you can generate self-cert via:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout admin.key -out admin.crt -subj "/CN=example.com"`

**First way:**

- Create secret: `kubectl create secret tls kong-admin-tls --cert=./admin.crt --key=./admin.key`
- Add `tls: kong-admin-tls` under admin ingress to values.yaml, example:

  ```yaml
  kong:
  ...
    admin:
      ingress:
        tls: kong-admin-tls
  ```

**Second way:**

- Create secret: `kubectl create secret tls kong-admin-tls --cert=./admin.crt --key=./admin.key`
- Add secretVolumes to values.yaml:

  ```yaml
  kong:
  ...
    secretVolumes:
    - kong-proxy-tls
  ```
- Add env params to values.yaml:

  ```yaml
  kong:
  ...
    env:
      ssl_cert: /etc/secrets/kong-proxy-tls/tls.crt
      ssl_cert_key: /etc/secrets/kong-proxy-tls/tls.key
  ```
- Add tls enabled under admin:

  ```yaml
  kong:
  ...
    admin:
      tls:
        enabled: true
  ```
- If you need other certs (optional that are not need for admin ssl):

  ```yaml
  kong:
  ...
    secretVolumes:
      - kong-proxy-tls
      - kong-admin-tls
      - kong-mngr-tls
    env:
      ssl_cert: /etc/secrets/kong-proxy-tls/tls.crt
      ssl_cert_key: /etc/secrets/kong-proxy-tls/tls.key
      admin_ssl_cert: /etc/secrets/kong-admin-tls/tls.crt
      admin_ssl_cert_key: /etc/secrets/kong-admin-tls/tls.key
      admin_gui_ssl_cert: /etc/secrets/kong-mngr-tls/tls.crt
      admin_gui_ssl_cert_key: /etc/secrets/kong-mngr-tls/tls.key

    admin:
      tls:
        enabled: true
  ```